OpenSSH on Cygwin seems to implicitly assume that it should go into the background if ControlPersist is given
This command
ssh -M -S skt -N -o ControlPersist=60 localhost

when run from the Git Bash prompt on Windows, seems to behave as it were actually ssh -f -M ....  That is, it implicitly forks a background process and returns... Is this supposed to happen or is this a bug or...?
This is not actually a huge problem for me since I wanted -f all along, but I'm puzzled because it seems to not be doing even though I never asked it to.  I don't want to accidentally rely on a bug that may be fixed later or something.
